# Checking for an exception and other values in an if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, exception

Let's say I want to check the avarage of 2 test scores. I don't want the user to input any letters or a value less than 0.

What comes to my mind is this code:

```
while True:
    try:
        score1 = float(input('Enter the your 1st score: '))
        score2 = float(input('Enter the your 2nd score: '))
    except:
        print('Invalid value, try again...')
        continue

    if (score1 < 0 or score2 < 0):
        print('Invalid value, try again...')
        continue

    print(f'Your average is {(score1 + score2) / 2}')
    break
```

Is there a way to check for an exception and if a score is less than 0 in the same if statement?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you tried the code and it works, then that's all we can do for you here. This is not a discussion forum or a tutoring service or code quality workshop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not very efficient; but you can do this after loading `score2` in the `try`:

```py
score2 = float(input('Enter the your 2nd score: '))

assert score1 >= 0 and score2 >= 0

except:
...
```

and get rid of the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, the way to check for an exception is by using a `try:except:` block, not by using an 'if' statement.

So the answer to this question:

"Is there a way of checking for an exception with an 'if' statement?" is "no."

Your question was a little different. You asked whether you could (1) check for an exception and (2) evaluate another expression "in the same 'if' statement."  Since you can't even do the first thing in an 'if' statement, you clearly can't do both.